# Router navigation append component instead of relpace component

Tags: angular6

I am doing project on Angular6. After clicking on login button,It should navigate to dashboard.but it will show dashboard content on the same page. can anyone please help me to resolve
this problem.

Please find below link to view the screenshot.
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/79/vtPsDp.png

Here is my code.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CustomMaterialModule } from './material.module';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ContactUsComponent } from './contact-us/contact-us.component';
import { AboutUsComponent } from './about-us/about-us.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ContactUsComponent,
    AboutUsComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    UserComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CustomMaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ContactUsComponent } from './contact-us/contact-us.component';
import { AboutUsComponent } from './about-us/about-us.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';


const routes: Routes = [
{
path:'home',
component:HomeComponent
},
{
    path:'aboutUs',
    component:AboutUsComponent
},
{
    path:'contactUs',
    component:ContactUsComponent

},
{
    path:'dashboard',
    component:DashboardComponent
}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<html>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">

 <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img class="logo" src="assets/school-logo3.png" alt="">
        </a>
</div>

<div class="mx-auto order-0">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">AUSTIN ASSISTANT SCHOOL</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-collapse2">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div> 


    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100 order-3 dual-collapse2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="aboutUs">aboutUs</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="contactUs">contactUs</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

  </div>
</nav>

<div>
  <img class="logo1" src="assets/school_kidz.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  <app-login></app-login>
</div>


  <footer class="page-footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="fixed_footer">@Copyright 2019</div>
</footer>
</html>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

login.component.html

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h1>Login </h1>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="passowrd" [(ngModel)]="password">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="login()">Login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import { DashboardComponent } from 'src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component';
@Component({
selector: 'app-login',
templateUrl: './login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
email: string;
password: string;
constructor(private router : Router) { }
ngOnInit() {
}
login() {
if(this.email == 'n@gmail.com' && this.password == '123') {
this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
alert("right credentials");
}else {
alert("Invalid credentials.");
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, definitely login page will definitely be shown there, since your router-outlet is present below that.

So, you can solve it by just keeping the router-outlet in your app component.html

and add a route to login page in the app routing file.

{

path : '',

redirectTo : '/login',

pathMatch : 'full'

}

Comment: Yeah. I need to show login page in home page only, So I have included <app-login></app-login> in app.component.html. I have created login page, and I wrote function that, after clicking on login button, It should navigate to dashboard page. Here problem is after clicking on button it will load dashboard page content(Dashboard works) as I showed in screenshot, but in same page. I want that content in separate page.

Comment: So, instead of adding the selector on home page, below the navigation bar add router-outlet and in the routing of app module add the router as I mention above, then your problem will be solved